# Get Information From XML From A URL

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I'm trying to extract information from this URL https://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?zws-id=X1-ZWz18hxnbvw0ej_40oka&address=2912%20WEST%201ST%20STREET%20UNIT%201&citystatezip=Jacksonville%20FL%2032254

The information I want to extract is 102557, it can be found from this portion of the XML URL:

```
<zestimate>
<amount currency="USD">102557</amount>
```

I'm using this code to extract it and its giving me an "Object variable or With block variable not set" error message.

```
Sub GetInfo2()

    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim sdd As String
    Dim add As Variant
    Dim url As Range

    i = 2

    For Each url In Range(Cells(3, "M"), Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp))
        With Http
            .Open "GET", url, False
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With


        sdd = Html.querySelector("span[class='zsg-tooltip-launch_keyword']")(0).innerText
        i = i + 1
        DD.Cells(i, "J") = sdd

    Next url


End Sub
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Hi Skin! Im glad to see your name again. What a relief! The error is on ```sdd = Html.querySelector("span[class='zsg-tooltip-launch_keyword']")(0).innerText ```

Comment: don’t speak too soon. :-) I actually never got around to trying the async thing with your other issue and as for this one, I’d have to spend a bit of time of which I currently have none, maybe tomorrow though ... if you haven’t gotten your answer by then. Sorry! At least everyone knows which line it errors out at now.

Comment: Oh sure. I'm just happy to see your name appear on one of my questions again. You have always been a tremendous help, which I truly appreciate :)

Comment: Try and not use reserved words as your variable names (i.e. change `Http` to maybe `oHttp` and `Html` to `oHtml`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me.  You'll just need to modify it slightly to work for you ...

```
Sub GetInfo2()
    Dim objHttp As XMLHTTP60, objXml As DOMDocument60, strUrl As String

    Set objHttp = New XMLHTTP60
    Set objXml = New DOMDocument60

    strUrl = "https://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?zws-id=X1-ZWz18hxnbvw0ej_40oka&address=2912%20WEST%201ST%20STREET%20UNIT%201&citystatezip=Jacksonville%20FL%2032254"

    With objHttp
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .send
    End With

    If objXml.LoadXML(objHttp.responseText) Then
        Debug.Print objXml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("response/results/result/zestimate/amount").Text
    End If
End Sub
```

... obviously I stripped it back to the raw call so I could target the specifics.

This also works ...

```
objXml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//amount").Text
```

... just be careful with that one though.

Comment: Thanks,  Skin! I have modified my code an appended yours into it. Part of my code is now this: ```If objXml.LoadXML(objHttp.responseText) Then
        Debug.Print objXml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("response/results/result/zestimate/amount").Text
        End If
        i = i + 1
        DD.Cells(i, "J") = sdd``` I get an error on ```DD.Cells(i, "J") = sdd```. I also cant assign sdd to ```Debug.Print objXml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("response/results/result/zestimate/amount").Text```

Comment: @SoaringRioren remove debug.print, all that does is write it out to the immediate window for debugging purposes. It’s a bit like console.writeline in other languages. Does that make sense? Essentially, replace debug.print with sdd =

Comment: And he does it again! Simply amazing! Your solution is neat and elegant. Thank you so much. Truly appreciate your speedy help, as always.

Comment: @SoaringRioren you’re full of compliments aren’t ya? Ha ha! No worries, glad I could help.

Comment: Im just appreciative. I didnt expect the answer to be this fast, simple and elegant. :)

Comment: @SoaringRioren it’s nice to see some people are. Others on here just take advantage of people’s time so being appreciative is what brings people like me back here to help others.